# In JPA, is there a way to ignore timezones on a date?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jaxb

I have an entity representing a person and it has a `java.util.Date dateOfBirth` field.  When someone sends us this entity to insert or update, we want to ignore the timezone of the date:  Even if you're visiting Japan, your date of birth is the same as when you're in New York, right?

The problem is, when the Date comes in externally, Java is interpreting the date to be in our timezone.  So if someone sends it from a different timezone, the date may shifted back or forward by a day.  There  are ways of dealing with this in Java code (it always makes my head hurt), but I was hoping there's a way that JPA/eclipselink could make my life easier somehow.  Perhaps there's a way to tell it to ignore timezones and the time component, even if the actual java class has these fields set?

If JPA supports this, how do I use it?  If JPA doesn't support this, what's a general strategy I can use to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this date coming in via XML by any chance?

Comment: @SteveC Well JAXB is deserializing it.  I'm not sure if that's a "yes" though.  I'm using Jersey and SOAP web services

Comment: This means that this is not a JPA issue, it is a JAXB issue. You need to customise your JAXB parsing to ignore the time zone information in the date. It would be better if the sender excluded the time zone in the first place.

Comment: As SteveC explained, you should correct the problem where it occurs: in the root cause, and namely when the date enters your code, when it is parsed from String to a Java Date.

Comment: If root cause is JPA, you should see [jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) or [jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), Else you should use an @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to parse the timezone.

Comment: @SteveC OK so how do I fix this if the DOB should ignore timezones and another date like `lastLogin` shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

If the field for date of birth is defined (in the XML Schema) as xsd:date, I cannot imagine how this shift can happen, provided a modicum of circumspection is observed.

The Java code should be:

```
@XmlElement(name = "dob", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar dob;
```

and after unmarshalling

```
 System.out.println( orgs.getDob().getYear() + "-" + 
                     orgs.getDob().getMonth() + "-" + 
                     orgs.getDob().getDay() );
```

will return `2002-10-10` for all sorts of values

```
<dob>2002-10-10-11:00</dob>
<dob>2002-10-10+11:00</dob>
<dob>2002-10-10+00:00</dob>
```

running from CEST.